# Run a function once flash movie has finished loading

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is it possible to set a listener or something like it to run a function once the flash movie itself has finished loading?

So something like:
When this flash movie has finished loading, activate function.

Btw. I'm not trying to do this with a swf file loaded into another flash movie. I need this to be done by the movie once it self has finished loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "LoaderInfo" object, with "Event.COMPLETE".

Ex:

stage.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onComplete);

function onComplete(e:Event) {
    trace("loaded.");
}

Comment: stage.loaderInfo threw me some errors, but this.loaderInfo worked like a charm. Cheers.